Sticky mouse pointer when using VMware Horizon Client
I'm using VMware Horizon Client Version 2406.1, Build 8.13.1 (11490701655) on a M2 Mac Studio connecting to a Windows 10 workstation.  In single monitor mode it works fine, but when using two or all three of my monitors, the mouse inconsistently get's stuck.  I know there is a keyboard solution that will 'un-stick' it in the moment.  But it just gets stuck again right away.  Giving a quick long movement with the mouse also fixes it temporarily.  This quick movement causes the mouse to reappear on another monitor.
I've tried switching the connection from VMware Blast to PCoIP and don't see any difference.  Has anyone found a way fix this permanently and allow for multiple monitors without mouse issues?

I know it’s only been 5 days but did you have any luck resolving this? Currently using 2 monitors with my M1 Pro Macbook and experiencing the same issue, the mouse constantly gets stuck and I have to give it a real shake to unstick it. Scrolling with the mouse wheel is also insanely fast to the point where its basically unusable, are you experiencing this as well? Not sure if this can be fixed in settings or if using a different mouse/trackpad would work.

I had a similar issue; I had the icons lagging as a mouse-pointer. E.g. a typing icon on the mouse-pointer did not change back to a hand or default.
The only way I was able to workaround this was by uninstalling this version and going back to 2312.1
